# Is $8^x$ positive or negative?

Tags: fake-proofs

What is wrong with this logic?

$8^x = (\sqrt{8}^2)^x = (\sqrt{8}^x)^2 \Rightarrow 8^x \geq 0 \forall x$

Edit: Clarification, the answer to $8^{1/2}$ permits both $\sqrt{8}$ and $-\sqrt{8}$ (hence my confusion). That would also suggest $8^x$ is not a well defined function?

Comment: what if x is not real number? then also is it correct?

Comment: In $\mathbb R$ that's correct. In $\mathbb {C}$, nobody told you that $a\ge 0$ (e.g taking $x=i$ you get -0.5+0.87i).

Comment: $8^{i \pi /\text{ln }8} = -1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is confusing you is that $9^{1/2}=3$ and $9^{1/2}\ne -3$.

We want the square root ($x^{1/2}$) to be a function, for this purpose you should get one and only one answer for any $x$. This means that "The square root of $9$ is a number whose square is $9$" is wrong, because then you can get different answers depending on who you ask, you always want to get the same answer. Which means you need to pick one of the numbers to be the square root of $9$. This is a convention that we prefer the nonnegative solution to the nonpositive.

Comment: This question always gets into student's minds. Nice observations +1

Answer (score 5):

What is special about the number 8 ? Do you know that $a^x=e^{x\log a}>0$ for all $a>0$?

Simply **the exponential function is positive**.

Comment: The source of my confusion is: $8^{1/2} = \sqrt{8}$ or $-\sqrt{8}$.

Comment: @EricHuang: Usually, $\log(8)$ is taken to be a real number. If so, then $8^{1/2}=e^{\frac12\large\log(8)}$ is a positive real.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $x$ is a real number, nothing is wrong with it. The conclusion is true.

[image]

Comment: What's the plot for?

Comment: I voted this down:  A plot may suggest an answer in mathematics, but it is not an answer in itself.  For example, from your response, how can we conlclude that $8^x \ge 0$ when  $|x| > 3$?

Comment: @StephenHerschkorn A reasonable answer is given right in question: while it is perhaps in need of rigor, there's no reason that such rigor cannot be easily be added to the OP's argument. The OP seems confused, though, thinking his conclusion is false. The plot is intended as an aid to help the OP identify the source of his confusion.